# Transferring file information to discord forums

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, electron

What I'm trying to do is get the files from my local hard drive and transfer them to a discord forum but when I run it I'm now getting an error saying that it cannot read the properties of undefined (reading 'MessageAttachment'). I'm not too sure if the way that I'm sending my files is incorrect or if the ipcRenderer is incorrect all together

```
// main.js

// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { channel } = require('diagnostics_channel')
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path')
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Discord } = require('discord.js')
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment('.csv');
const client = new Client({
     intents: [
      GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
      GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ]
})
const fs = require('fs')

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
    enableRemoteModule: true,
    contextIsolation: false,
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
   mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  client.login('MTA5OTkwOTgxMjQ0NTI1MzcxMw.GsBeUK.VGFbkE6iPrhB8uU3uc-trjtUzAl-lqhFaIjExY')
  createWindow()

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
});

  app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.

ipcMain.handle('upload-folder', (event, folderPath) => {
  const channel = client.channels.fetch('1099920935307456515')
    if (!channel) return console.log('Invalid channel ID');
    fs.readdir(folderPath, (err, files) => {
      if (err) return event.reply('upload-folder-reply', err.message)
      files.forEach((file) => {
        const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
        MessageAttachment.channel.send({
          files: [filePath]
        })
          .then(() => {
            const message = `Uploaded file: ${file}`
            channel.send(message)
          })
          .catch((error) => event.reply('upload-folder-reply', error.message))
          //console.log(folderPath)
        });
      const message = `Uploaded ${files.length} file${files.length === 1 ? '' : 's'}`
      channel.send(message)
      console.log(files)
  })})
```

// preload.js

````
// All the Node.js APIs are available in the preload process.
// It has the same sandbox as a Chrome extension.
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
      const element = document.getElementById(selector)
      if (element) element.innerText = text
    }
  
    for (const dependency of ['chrome', 'node', 'electron']) {
      replaceText(`${dependency}-version`, process.versions[dependency])
    }
  })```
````

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
        <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
        Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
        and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.
      </body>
     
    </html>
```

renderer.js

```
    const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
        const ipc = ipcRenderer;
        
        ipcRenderer.invoke('upload-folder', 'Navcom/aar/')
          .then(() => console.log('Folder uploaded successfully'))
          .catch((error) => console.error(error))
```

What should be happening is that the renderer.js takes every file one at a time within the folder and uploads it to a discord forum within the channel ID but when I was testing this it doesn't do anything no error messages nothing, the bot does go online which is expected but it doesn't grab the selected folder in renderer.js or uploads them within the ipc main.  Any help on this issue is appreciated

[image]